# Does MVC OutputCaching take preference over setting cache response headers?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, caching, outputcache

This question is related to [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4078011/how-to-switch-off-caching-for-mvc-requests-but-not-for-static-files-in-iis7).

I have an MVC application with caching disabled for all controller actions. I do this by setting cache response headers in `Application_BeginRequest`:

```
    protected void Application_BeginRequest()
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1));
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(false);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetRevalidation(HttpCacheRevalidation.AllCaches);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
    }
```

There is single controller action for which I do want caching enabled. I have decorated this action with the `OutputCache` attribute:

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 300, VaryByParam = "id")]
```

What happens now for this action? Does it get cached because of the OutputCache attribute, or is it not cached because of the response headers?

**-- EDIT --**

As it seems, the response headers take preference. So my question becomes: how can I enable cache for single controller actions? Overwrite the response headers again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The response headers enforce the cache control. The solution was not to set response headers for controller actions that require caching. Instead of using `OutputCache`, I'm now using a custom cache attribute that also sets an `ISCACHED` key in the request items dictionary. The code snippet from my question was changed to this:

```
    protected void Application_EndRequest()
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Items["ISCACHED"] == null)
        {
            var cache = HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache;
            cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            cache.SetNoStore();
            cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1));
        }
    }
```

I had to move this from `BeginRequest` to `EndRequest`, to allow actions to set the `ISCACHED` request item first. If it is set, a controller already handled caching for this request, otherwise caching is disabled.

Answer (score 7):

The two things are separate; the response cache is *primarily* looking at what the *client* sees - what they will use without hitting the server, or what modified-date they will send up to the server.

OutputCache, however, is focused at the *server*; the request will still *happen* (unlike something cached at the client), but it is possible (hopefully likely) that your method won't be called: instead, the cached version will be returned.

So: it is *not cached* at the client; a HTTP request is made, and (for requests within 5 minutes, for the same `id`, memory permitting) the *cached* version is returned from the server (typically reducing IO and CPU load at the server). Make sense?

Comment: This is only partly true. The [OutputCacheLocation.Any value from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.outputcachelocation.aspx): "The output cache can be located on the browser client (where the request originated), on a proxy server (or any other server) participating in the request, or on the server where the request was processed." So what will happen to the client cache in this case?