# Application_BeginRequest not firing for cached results?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, caching, global-asax

I`m writing an ASP.NET MVC application using IIS 7.5 as web server.
I would like to open a DB connection at the begin of any request and close this connection at the end of the request.

Therefore, in global.asax I specify the member

```
Public Shared conn As OleDbConnection
```

In the Application_BeginRequest handler I open the connection like this:

```
Sub Application_BeginRequest(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
   Dim strConn As String = "myConnectionString..."
   conn = New OleDbConnection(strConn)
   conn.Open()
End Sub 'Application_BeginRequest
```

And in the Application_EndRequest handler I close it:

```
Sub Application_EndRequest(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
   conn.Close()
   conn.Dispose()
End Sub 'Application_EndRequest
```

Then, maybe in the Index() method of the HomeController, I use the Db connection provided by the global.asax:

```
Dim _conn As OleDbConnection = MvcApplication.conn
'[then get or set data in the DB...]
```

I now experience a strange thing: The DB connection is opened properly when I completely reload a page from the server. When IIS delivers the page from cache, the DB connection is not openend and I get an error (although seemingly from my reporting tool the Application_BeginRequest handler IS entered). Is there a way to overcome this problem? I already tried setting the cache control via HTML metatags and by leveraging the following Q&A provided here: [How to switch off caching for MVC requests but not for static files in IIS7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4078011/how-to-switch-off-caching-for-mvc-requests-but-not-for-static-files-in-iis7)
The problem still remains. Can anyone help?
Many thanks,
niewi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shared variables are ... shared across requests. That means that two concurrent requests will trample over each others connection. This is what you might be observing.

Store the connection in `HttpContext.Items`.